# How to avoid re-rendering react DropdownList from react-widgets

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm using the DropdownList from `react-widgets`to make a dropdown menu from a json file (`lang` has the values). Here is the code:

```
        <DropdownList 
            ref='dropdown'
            data={lang} 
            valueField='id'
            textField={item => item.name}
            caseSensitive={false} 
            filter='contains'
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleLangChange} />
```

The problem is that the list is huge!!! and so rendering it takes time and when the user wants to select an item he had to wait for couple of seconds. Does anyone knows how can I make it faster? 
It seems that it's rendering the `DropdownList`component each time the search input is updated :/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [React lifecycle shouldComponentUpdate() method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate). It is responsible for notifying `React` if component should be re-rendered. You could enforce re-rendering ONLY when dropdown elements are modified.

Not sure how much access over React-Widgets you have. But you clearly can create a wrap component around DropDownList to have access to properties and `shouldComponentUpdate`. Just an idea